# Does SBB's EasyRide work with public transit in Basel Stadt and Basel Landschaft?

Tags: switzerland, basel

The Swiss rail company, SBB, has something called EasyRide in the SBB Android app.  You hop on some form of transit, turn it on, and then turn it off again at the end of your journey.  Then it figures out the most cost-effective ticket that would cover your trip and bills you for it (e.g. to your credit card).

I assume this works with trains in and around Basel, but does it also work with other forms of public transit in Basel?  Can I use it in trams and busses?

Comment: The FAQ at https://www.sbb.ch/en/timetable/mobile-apps/sbb-mobile/easyride/faq.html has a "where can I use EasyRide" with a PDF of all covered transit options. "EasyRide can be used on the entire GA route network in Switzerland"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [SBB website](https://www.sbb.ch/en/timetable/mobile-apps/sbb-mobile/easyride.html), EasyRide is available on

> train, postbus, boat and urban transport. The EasyRide ticket is valid on the entire GA network

GA is the annual subscription system of SBB. The area of validity of the GA is described in [this document](https://www.sbb.ch/content/dam/sbb/de/pdf/abos-billette/abonnemente/ga/karte-geltungsbereich-ga-halbtax_en_barrierefrei.pdf.sbbdownload.pdf), and it includes (along with dozens of other networks):

- the BVB network (green trams and buses)
- the BLT network (yellow and red trams and buses)

In short: **Yes**.

Comment: Looking at that document, this seems like an important caveat: "Basel BVB Basler Verkehrsbetriebe (inkl. Linie 8 bis Haltestelle «Kleinhünigeranlage», Linie 38 bis Grenzacher Horn)".  Tram line 8 has three more stops after Kleinhünigeranlage; they are just across the border in Weil am Rhein, Germany.  It sounds as if perhaps those _can't_ be used with EasyRide.

Comment: And bus 38 seems to be a similar situation: It goes to Grenzach-Wyhlen, which is in Germany, not Switzerland.  So what happens if I use EasyRide to travel to Germany with tram 8 or bus 38?

Comment: Those stops outside Switzerland are not part of the GA area, so they are not covered. I suppose the moment you cross the border you are without a valid ticket.

Comment: @KristvanBesien that is not entirely true, not all stops outside Switzerland are not part of the GA, only the vast majority. There are a few lines operated by SBB outside of Switzerland (two worth naming are to Milan and Konstanz) on which the SBB GA is valid. Which is also mentioned in the document linked by jcarno

Comment: The GA is not valid till Milan. SBB also does not operate till Milan. The station of Domodossola serves as a joint Swiss-Italian station, and trains are operated till there by SBB (and the GA is valid) but they are operated by Trenitalia beyond . You can therefore not travel to Milan on your GA.

Comment: Fairtiq, the underlying technology for EasyRide, now works in the zones of RVL, the transport association in Landkreis Lörrach, just across the border from Basel.  So on Saturday I used Fairtiq to take the train from the Weil am Rhein area to Basel Badischer Bahnhof, and then EasyRide on the tram from there to Barfüsserplatz.  It worked!  (Unfortunately, it was also more expensive, round-trip, than just buying a TriRegio Mini pass. )

Comment: The bottom line is that while EasyRide does work with public transit (within the Swiss borders) and Fairtiq can be used in the nearby RVL area, the thing about clumping together all your trips and putting them on the cheapest ticket only works for tickets offered by one country.  Cross-border tickets like the TriRegio or TriRegio Mini aren't covered by Fairtiq/EasyRide and may still be cheaper.